# Precise cut of remote video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have hours long video files living on a server, and I need to be able to cut segments in them in an accurate and fast way.

I tried:

```
ffmpeg -ss 10:00 -i http://server/input.mp4 -t 5:00 -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.mp4
```

This works and is fast, but it's not precise as ffmpeg seeks backward until it finds a keyframe. The resulting video file ends up with a negative start time which is not working nice with browsers.

I know I can re-encode the video for accurate seeking, but this would be slow and lose quality.

I came up with the following idea:

For example, let's say we have a 20 seconds video, with keyframes every 5 secs, at 0,5,10,15,20.

If I want a segment from sec 2 to sec 17, I would re-encode from sec 2 to 5, vcopy from sec 5 to 15, re-encode from sec 15 to 17 and concat the three files.

This is the general problem and my idea, now the requirements are:

- Source files must be accessed over HTTP
- There must be no or very few quality loss
- It must be fast, cutting 10 minutes in a 2h video should take around 1-2 sec
- It must be accurate
- It must work for webm and mp4

It doesn't have to be a ffmpeg command, I'm quite sure I'll have to write a C wrapper around libav.

Source file can be pre-processed in any necessary way to make it work.

**UPDATE:** After getting more info, it seems my "idea" of gluing re-encoded extremities parts with a stream copied middle part won't work because of different encoding settings. But I could extract a longuer part (keyframe -> keyframe) and extract timecodes I could add in an HTTP header, like `Time-Range: 0.25,15.14`  which would mean "play from sec 0.25 to 15.14 and discard the rest".

Comment: Would it work for you to embed keyframes in the source at a high enough density that the accuracy problems was resolved?  For example if you preprocessed all your videos to have a keyframe every second, and then just let people cut only to seconds, it would seem your problem is basically solved.

Comment: negative start time? what version of ffmpeg?

Comment: did you ever solve this?